# Qt - accessing the bundle path

Tags: c++, macos, qt

The Qt documentation "[Mac Differences](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/mac-differences.html#mac-os-x-native-api-access)" page provides the following code for accessing an application's bundle path:

```
CFURLRef appUrlRef = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle());
CFStringRef macPath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(appUrlRef, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
const char *pathPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(macPath,CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
qDebug("Path = %s", pathPtr);
CFRelease(appUrlRef);
CFRelease(macPath);
```

However, what is the advantage of that over something simpler, like the following:

```
QDir dir = QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
dir.cdUp();
dir.cdUp();
return dir;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way with Qt 5 and OS X 10.9 or greater is:

```
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)CFAutorelease((CFURLRef)CFBundleCopyBundleURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle()));
QString path = QUrl::fromCFURL(url).path();
```

Comment: Yes, and this will also be correct for shallow bundles on iOS which do not have a Contents/MacOS subdirectory hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

**Never use the first code**. As written in the Qt documentation there, it might not work in a non-English environment, due to the  fact that the file name encoding is not by  `CFStringGetSystemEncoding()`, which returns the primary non-unicode encoding of the user.  Instead,  the file name is always encoded by UTF8 (with a slight variant.)

```
const char *pathPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(macPath, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

More precisely, you need to use [`CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation).

`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` (mostly) correctly takes into account these subtleties, so you should use the latter approach, if you want your app to work on non-English Macs.

Comment: Interesting... I wonder why Nokia puts that in the documentation despite its problems? I believe I've seen the second way written elsewhere in the documentation (or perhaps in one of the examples).

Comment: I guess that documentation is a very old one written long time ago. The code itself uses the (mostly) correct approach, and is well-maintained. You should file a bug report.